# Why is my training loss going up and down all the time?

Tags: regression

My training loss goes down and then up again. I am totally new to pytorch and neural networks in general so I guess it makes sense to explain my whole model. I probably messed up something really obvious. I am trying to predict 3 continuous values using 10 input variables. My target variables are days, hours and minutes. I was hoping to be able to make reliable predicitions regarding the days and the hours, I don't expect the NN to be exact regarding the minutes.
My NN-Architecture looks like this:

```
 class Net(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden, n_output):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden1 = torch.nn.Linear(10,1000)
        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(1000,3)   

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.hidden1(x))
        x = self.predict(x)
        return x

net= Net(n_feature=10, n_hidden=1000, n_output=3) 
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()  
EPOCHS = 50
```

[image]

I was already playing around using different number of hidden layers, neurons, higher or lower learning rate, different batch sizes, more and less data and so on. But I couldn't identify any significant improvement regarding the loss value. The predicted output is actually not that bad but I don't feel like it's learning what it's supposed to. I guess it's not about certain adjustments but more whether the architecture of my NN is appropriate for what I'm trying to do, so if anyone reads this, thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you scale the data first? What’s the largest and smallest learning rates you’ve used? Did you scale the targets also?

Comment: No. Originally the time was given in minutes only. Scaling seems quite important if the differences between the var are high. I splitted time in the three values days, hours and minutes in order to avoid scaling. Why? I felt like non of the scalers (MinMaxScaler, Normalizer) suited my problem. If one sample (one row) contains three identical times, they have to be identical, therefore I used Normalizer. But the relations between the samples matter as well, that is if the time of let's say sample 12 and sample 453 are the same, they shoud be the same after scaling. Learning rate: 0.1 - 0.00001.